# FinancialAppAPI/' does not have a commit checked out

Tags: git, gitlab

I've 2 library projects and one is solution file in asp.net core.
I choose Main directory,
I execute git,

```
git init
```

then,

```
git status
```

I see three folders to untrack
like below,

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitattributes
        .gitignore
        DAL/
        DataModel/
        FinancialAppAPI/
```

Then, i run,

```
git add .

PS D:\Lectures\LearningProjects\client\FinancialApp> git add .
```

then, i get this error,

```
error: 'FinancialAppAPI/' does not have a commit checked out

fatal: adding files failed
```

So, i try many git commands so for, i can not be successful to resolve this issue.

```
Actually, i just create my project, and first time i'm pushing it to github.
```

Can any one help please!
I would be greatful!

Comment: If someone asked you the same question the way you wrote it, would you be able to understand it?

Comment: Updated, please now have a look!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error usually comes from submodules issues.

Probably the file `.gitattributes` is referencing a submodule which is not available in your project.

Try this:

```bash
rm -rf .git
rm .gitattributes
git init
git add --all
```

Comment: I remove it and run again,
git add .
but still facing same issue

Comment: gitattributes does not exist,,, and error still same after following above commands